# Does WEBVIEW Android support VLC web plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, android-webview, vlc

Google Chrome seems kill the support NPAPI recently. I'd like to know whether I can use vlc web plugin for android webview or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android web browsers never supported any kind of web plugins so there is technically no way to develop a VLC web plugin. However, you can use the native VLC app and open it from a browser with a media source URL using the vlc:// pseudo protocol.